# How do I extract from a password protected zip file using VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook, password-protection, unzip

I have been struggling with this problem for quite some time now, and have trawled through various forums trying to find an answer.

I have a mailbox which received 5 emails each morning which have zipped, password-protected .csv files which require opening and processing in Excel. I am semi-competent in VBA so the Excel side of things is no issue, but it would save me a lot of time if I could automatically unzip these files and save them to a folder.

These emails have the same subjects, attachments and passwords each day, and are from the same sender to the same mailbox. I have code which can automatically process and save the .zip files to a location, but I am still stuck with the problem of having to go into each one, enter the password, open the file, save it, etc.

I have refrained from attaching this code because I would like to see if there are better solutions to my one, and it is the unzipping and password entering that I really need help with. This being said if you would like me to attach my code I will be happy to do so :)

Comment: So this is really *How do I extract from a password protected zip file?* If so take a look at the Info-Zip library; http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/Libraries/Compression/Unzipping_Files/article.asp

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I will amend the title. Although I would be very keen on any solutions using VBA, most likely within Outlook itself. The VB solution seems to imply it would still prompt for the password, but if this is the only option I will explore VB as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

To expand my comment, no input is required - the password is obtained via an event so can be provided in code.

Download the demo project and DLL

In the outlook VBA editor, right click the Project in the tree, *Import File* and add

```
cUnzip.cls
mUnzip.bas
```

Put the DLL in \System32 (or \SysWoW64 on 64bit)

As a naive example, add a new class `cWhatever`:

```
Private WithEvents Unzip As cUnzip

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set Unzip = New cUnzip
End Sub

Sub RunUnzip()
    With Unzip
        .ZipFile = "c:\blah\qqq.zip"
        .UnzipFolder = "c:\temp"
        .Unzip
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Unzip_PasswordRequest(sPassword As String, bCancel As Boolean)
    sPassword = "password123"
End Sub
```

Then to run from elsewhere:

```
Dim x As New cWhatever
x.RunUnzip
```

First time you run there is an error highlighting `App.EXEName`, just delete the `App.EXEName &`

Comment: Thanks for the above Alex, this makes things a lot clearer. Unfortunately downloading executables is restricted at work, so I will have to wait until I get home before I can test this out. You've been really helpful though, so thanks again :)